# JUnit Tests Failing After Upgrading to SDK 1.9.17

Tags: java, google-app-engine, junit

We recently updated to AppEngine SDK 1.9.17.  When I try to run my JUnit tests I get errors any time I try to access the datastore using JDO.  Specifically the error I get is:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.repackaged.com.google.io.protocol.ProtocolMessage.storeStringsOnlyAsBytes()Z
at com.google.storage.onestore.v3.OnestoreEntity$Reference.setApp(OnestoreEntity.java:6598)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyTranslator.convertToPb(KeyTranslator.java:50)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.EntityTranslator.convertToPb(EntityTranslator.java:48)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:178)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.toPb(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:155)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$BatchIterator.<init>(Batcher.java:180)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher$2.<init>(Batcher.java:317)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Batcher.getBatches(Batcher.java:317)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.doBatchPut(AsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:365)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:293)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl$4.runInternal(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:261)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.TransactionRunner.runWriteInTransaction(TransactionRunner.java:53)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:258)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.put(BaseAsyncDatastoreServiceImpl.java:234)
at com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceImpl.put(DatastoreServiceImpl.java:56)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.WrappedDatastoreService.put(WrappedDatastoreService.java:100)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.EntityUtils.putEntitiesIntoDatastore(EntityUtils.java:759)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObjectsInternal(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:314)
at com.google.appengine.datanucleus.DatastorePersistenceHandler.insertObject(DatastorePersistenceHandler.java:218)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.internalMakePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2381)
at org.datanucleus.state.JDOStateManager.makePersistent(JDOStateManager.java:2357)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectInternal(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1896)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObjectWork(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1745)
at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerImpl.persistObject(ObjectManagerImpl.java:1602)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.jdoMakePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:731)
at org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManager.makePersistent(JDOPersistenceManager.java:756)
...
```

I opened up a few of the jars that are typically dependent, and the repackaged com.google.io package is completely missing.

Things I've tried:

1. Updated my classpath for the JUnit tests from 1.9.14 to 1.9.17
2. Tried adding in the additional google_sql.jar in the lib/impl directory
3. Removing all lib/impl jars, then add them back one at a time

Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ha!  As part of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Java_Introducing_the_Java_testing_utilities) for JUnit and AppEngine you must copy two files to the WEB-INF/lib directory of your project.

```
appengine-api-labs.jar
appengine-testing.jar
```

When upgrading, not only do you have to update your JUnit Debug Configuration in Eclipse, but you also have to update (copy/overwrite) these two files from the later SDK.